# Android Listview Searching from edittext

Tags: android, database, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

now i am making a program in android using edittext and listview. I want to search the listview item using edittext above. After populate data to listview, when user type text in edittext, the listview will scroll to the position start with that text. Example: i have item: apple, application, book, boy, car, cat, cash..... when i type b in edittext then listview will scroll to book. I want to use the listview.setSelection(position), but i don't know how can i get the position from my edittext search. I hope everybody can help me. Thanks in advances !

Comment: I guess you are using textwatcher.. either you maintain a separate arraylist for filtered list or compare id by the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in following steps.

1. Check that that word user entered is available in your listview.
2. If yes then get id or position of that word in array list or your listview respectively.
3. then set selection to retrieved id.

if you are still not able to get id then pleas post your code you are using string array custom array adapter

Sol:

In your case it could be like

this code should be in your oncreate or wherever you are initlizing your listview

```
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int i=0; i<arrlist.size();i++)
{
    map.put(arrlist.get(i).trim().toLowerCase(), ""+i+1);
}
```

to get value from hash map
this code will on your search button click

```
 String id= map.get("yourserchitem")
 lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1);
```

on text changer write this code
here e is object of my editext

```
e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arr.contains(e.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()))
            {
                String id= map.get(e.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase());
                lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1);
            }
        }
    });
```

change code inside afterTextChanged with

```
String middle_string="";
             for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
                {
                    if(arr.get(i).startsWith(e.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        middle_string=arr.get(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            if(arr.contains(middle_string))
            {
                String id= map.get(middle_string);
                lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1);
            }
```

Comment: I have already test with this: it work, but i have more than 20,000 entries, so everytime my edittext change: it has to loop to find the id and then select that id. So, this make my program runs slow. How can i do to make it run faster? :
for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) 
   { 
    if(list.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toString())) 
    {
      pos = i;
     break; 
     } 
    } 
  lv.setSelection(pos);

Comment: then you should associate each entry with an id. you can use hash map for that. In hash map use name as key and id as value and instead of iterating through complete list you can simply get id by passing name as key on click of search button.

Comment: Dear sir, can you tell me more detail about how to use hash map?
Please show me code about this! thanks

Comment: where do i put this code? i put in myedittext.Textchange() event, is it correct? 
for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) 
   { 
    
      map.put(list.get(i).trim().toLowerCase(), ""+i+1);
      
      
    
     
    } 
   
   String id= map.get(s.toString());
   lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1);

Comment: chk edited answer and use String id= map.get(s.toString().trim().toLowerCase());

Comment: is it ok if i put: String id= map.get("yourserchitem")
 lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1);  on textchange? Mean that when i type the first letter of words, it will jump to position of that words in listview? i don't want to use Button Search

Comment: yes it will work there too. you can use it in aftertextchanged method of your textwatcher

Comment: But why it force stop when i start my searching? my purpose: is when i type: s then it will jump to letter start with s. 
i use this, is it correct? 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String id= map.get(e.toString());
    lv.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(id)-1); 
  }

Comment: what error you get there and please use to lower case and trim method on e.gettext().toString().trim().toLowerCase()

Comment: it still error. my purpose: is when i type: s then it will jump to letter start with s in listview. With this using, can it work with my purpose, sir?

Comment: no to jump at all letter start with s you should use AutoCompleteTextView here. It will be more appropriate choice for your purpose.

Comment: So, what does hash map in here practice? if i use this and it runs, so how is it operation search listview?

Comment: i think hashmap will be more useful if you use hashmap on button click but if you want to use it here you have to check some condition before getting id and make selection like that searched word is equal to any word in your list. It will display slection according to one word not for all complete word starting from s. you list will focus on "Sun" if you searched for and there will be other items too. place an if condistion brfore getting id to check searched item is in list or not

Comment: I do with Button Click it work well, can you show me how to get only the first letter and use in TextChange as my purpose? thanks

Comment: Thaks you! it work well, but if i want it to show in only startup letter of the word, how can i do ? Example: i only type c then all letter start with c will jump to that position.

Comment: then you should use auto complete text view and set list accordingly

Comment: you can aslo search for words in your array list starting with c and get first word of that letter and then get id and set selection.

Comment: Can u show me code? because i am new to this . Thanks you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of AutoCompleteTextView(ACTV).

Just pass the array of words you have to ACTV. so when user starts typing the words will be predicted based on the array of words you have.This is more like a google instant search.Try and let us know

Comment: I know it! but in my case, i want to use listview! can you tell me how can i do with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String [] items;
ArrayList<String> listview;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView lst_view1;
EditText edt_text1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);

    lst_view1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_view1);
    edt_text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_text1);
    initlist();
    edt_text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                initlist();
            } else {
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

public void searchItem (String textTosearch){
    for(String item:items){
        if(!item.contains(textTosearch)){
            listview.remove(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void initlist() {
    items = new String [] {"iran","usa","canada","russia","tehran","yazd","esfahan","amir","rose",
            "hashemi","rezvani","ardebil","microsoft","google","amazon","tesla-motors"};
    listview = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtview1 , listview);
    lst_view1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```